# How we can put image button below corner of circle image in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have circle image, and I want to put pencil image button like below in image, I try to use
`.padding(.vertical, 40) .padding(.horizontal,20)`

or

```
.padding(.top,40)
        .padding(.leading,20)
```

but it is not work. Any idea?

[image]

```
 ZStack{
                    
                
                    Image("image")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
               
        Button() {
                
               } label: {
                Image("pencil")
             
               }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve the layout by calculating the right offset for the camera Button as you want the button to be placed on the edge of the circle:

```
let radius: CGFloat = 100
var offset: CGFloat {
    sqrt(radius * radius / 2)
}

var body: some View {
    Image(imageName)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(
            width: radius * 2,
            height: radius * 2)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .overlay(
            Button(action: {}) {
                
                Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .padding(8)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .background(
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                    )
            }.offset(x: offset, y: offset)
        )
}
```

gives a result like this:

[image: sample image]

You could obviously either hardcode the radius of the circle or pass it into the initialiser of this View if needed.

Comment: it is great solutioni tnx so so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Set alignment of `ZStack`

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){ //<-- Here
    Image("image")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
        .clipShape(Circle())
    
    Button() {
        
    } label: {
        Image("pencil")
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: tnx so much, is it possible add .leading or .trailing after "(alignment: .bottomTrailing)"?

Comment: I do but button padding from content, I want to padding whole button without content

Comment: without content means? and what is your content?

Comment: I mean icon padding form its origin, not padding from direction, is it possible  U add example padding in ur answer

Comment: when I use the ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing), it work but pencil button located outside of circle image, I want to padding pencil  button to top

Comment: it because your ZStack container size is big the image circle size. then you ```.overlay``` to image and set ```.bottomTrailing``` alignment to a button by frame alignment.

Comment: like this ```    Image("image")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .overlay(
            Button() {
                
            } label: {
                Image("pencil")
            }.frame(alignment: .bottomTrailing)
        )```

Comment: but image icon now located in center of circle image

Comment: it is not work, is it possible padding pencil button?